# Searching for Manuel Amigo, Pontevedra, Spain 1896

Tags: spain

I’m looking for help finding a link back to Spain for my grandfather, Manuel Amigo. I don’t know anything about his family in Spain. He left around 1914 and went to Cuba, no records of that found but I found the manifest when he landed at Ellis Island in 1916. He was born Aug. 30th either 1896 or 1894 in Pontevedra. I did find a link to some sort of search but it’s in Spanish and I can’t navigate it.

Comment: How do you know that he came to America from Spain via Cuba?  I think you should focus your question on something like finding a record of him in Cuba (if you don’t have one), finding his baptism or birth record in Spain, or something else of particular interest.

Comment: All of the documents I’ve found on him say Pontevedra Spain. I also remember as a kid an Aunt going to Spain and seeing his family, they are all passed now so nobody to ask specific questions to.

Comment: What type of documents have you found on him that state his place and date of birth?  These are likely to be strong evidence for where and when he was born.

Comment: I only have the manifest from his arrival at Ellis Island, it only says 8/30/1896 Pontevedre Spain

Comment: Ancestry.com has his petition for naturalization, his WWI and WWII registration cards. Those also say Pontevedra Spain and 30 Aug 1894. Also he was unmarried at time of petition. The petition gives the name of the ship he arrived on from Cuba. If you don't have an Ancestry.com subscription, you might be able to get access through your local public library.

Comment: Did he married in a catholic church? He would have been likely baptised in Spain, and in order to get married the parish where he married should have requested approval to the original parish. If that is the case, look for the marriage certificate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what exactly you are looking for with regards to information about your grandfather. A good place to start with is probably his birth certificate. This will list the names of his parents at the very least. You can get the birth certificate from the local registry office in Pontevedra.

Once you have that, depending on the brevity of the document, you might have an address or at least the area of Pontevedra where his parents lived. You can then find the local parish where he would have been baptised. Church records often times have far more information than registry documents. The record comes in form of a book, which you may be able to peruse at your leisure. This means you can go back and forwards a few years to see whether your grandfather had any siblings (which seems likely given your aunt's trips there). You might need to go in person though...

Finding descendants of those siblings will be a bit harder, but could be as simple as a local phone book if they still live in the area.

As for the language barrier. I find GoogleTranslate gets you a long way. The translations are usually good enough to be understood, even if they can't get nuance across as well. If you would rather have a human look over it, you could try the genealogy reddit or Discord server. Folks there are usually very friendly and happy to help.